# replace Sunfish flotation blocks

Tags: boats, sailing, repairs

My sunfish got to be over two hundred lbs.I opened up the forward deck to find only expanding foam. No Styrofoam. I see pics of the Styrofoam but need the specs/dimensions of the Styrofoam. I have been drying the foam (slow process) but Styrofoam would provide better balance

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "I opened up the forward deck" how big of a opening do you have?  I don't have an answer to your question, but see this related post for some possible help [What to look for in Marine Grade Expanding Foams](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/14218/4079)

Answer (score 1):

The best bet on a job like this is to stick a tape measure across it and see what you've got. While technically a "one design" hull a modern sunfish is a long way from a classic one and a wooden hull may have changed shape over the years.

Styrofoam and the like comes in standard sizes so if you're doing the job yourself you'll be buying blocks and carving them down. You should also do a full check of the hull integrity while you've got the top off as it sounds like you have a persistent leak to get into this situation.

Comment: The sunfish is all fiberglass, not wooden.

Comment: The original 1953 sunfish was wooden, and I've actually seen one way back in the 1980s.  But anything likely to be seen floating now is probably fiberglass.